# Hash-List with STL - Can I point to an item in an STL list to another item?

Tags: c++, stl

Let's say I have a:

```
std::vector<std::list<Node> >
```

And let's say Node is:

```
class Node { 
    Node* next;
    int data;
};
```

The vector cells correspond to hash function values for fast look-ups.  The idea is you insert your elements to the vector, but still chain them together with the Node-> next member.  So you have a list where the elements can efficiently be looked up by key using a hash function to find the correct vector cell to start from.

Anyway, all that aside.  My question is:

Can I have my Node::next pointers point to other nodes in a list (be it the same one, or another one from a different vector cell) without causing problems?  I wasn't sure if the standard library implementation of a list would allow this.  I seem to be running into problems (my code's not accessible here) and I wanted to see if this could be the cause.

Comment: As far as I know, std::list and std::vector allocate a certain bunch of memory, and, when adding items, might move all items to a different part of memory when there is not enough space to fit all in the first place.

This would obviously lead to problems in this code.

Comment: I was aware std::vector did that as it requires contiguous memory - I wouldn't have expected it from a list though since it would involve extra copying of elements for no benefit.  Are you sure list does this?

Comment: @nijansen you're correct about `std::vector`, but `std::list` does not move items. (of course, with a `list` inside a `vector`, there is the possibility that the `list` will be copied.)

Comment: You could work around such a limitation using smart pointers, but that might be overkill for the Node structure. How about writing a container class that fulfills all requirements yourself?

Comment: @nijansen: True for vector but not list. All references to list members are safe to modifications to the list (unless the actual member being referenced is removed). But note: In this case because the list may be copied as the vector is enlarged (C++03 not true in C++11) the old version of the list may be destroyed.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm using the vector as a statically sized structure for the most part.  If my collision lists get too long I manually enlarge it, but I haven't messed around with that yet - for now it just remains the size I initialized it to in the constructor.

Comment: @onitake - I've actually written my own basically, I just decided it would be fun to try and do it with STL components for a learning experience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to point to other nodes in the list, that's totally doable, yes.  However, I would propose a different design: a `std::list<int>` and a `std::unordered_map<int, std::list<int>::iterator>`, both members of a class who's only purpose is to keep the two containers synchonized.  This should be easier, safer, and faster than (my interpretation of) your current plan.

Adding and removing objects to both lists is a breeze:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::list<int>::iterator> fast;
std::list<int> linked;

void add(int data) {
    fast[data] = linked.insert(linked.end(), data);
};
std::list<int>::iterator erase(std::list<int>::iterator iter) {
    fast.erase(*iter);
    return linked.erase(iter);        
}
```

Comment: Dangit, stupid phone.  Can someone change those to backticks so it displays properly?

Comment: I didn't fix the <> symbols because the contents confusing me - someone else can do that :p

Comment: How can I get the pointer to the last element I push_backed into the list so I can store it for later use?  I think I know but that's the part which doesn't seem to work right.

Comment: @w00te: I added simple functions to add and remove.

Answer (score 1):

STL lists are doubly linked and have private previous and next pointers.  The next pointer in your element will not be related to the list's next pointer so it can be anything you want.  You will have to manage it yourself.  It looks like you are implementing a hash with a linked list for hash collisions (says clippy).  Have you looked at the map container?

Comment: How can I get the pointer to the last element I push_backed into the list so I can store it for later use?  I think I know but that's the part which doesn't seem to work right.

Comment: list::end method gives the last element of a list.

Comment: I actually worked out my problem.  I had been using &list.back() which was fine.  My problem was actually just a stupid mistake in my traversal function :(